# no matching function for call to error al compilar

Tags: c++, compilador

tengo una duda con un programa que hice, es una clase para hacer operaciones con vectores, creo dos vectores con el constructor de la clase, uno se pasa como parámetro a la función `suma()`, para sumar dos vectores, lo que pasa que me sale un error al compilar, que dice que hay referencias sin definir, el cual no entiendo:

Este es la clase con las cabeceras:

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

template <class T>

class vector_t{
private:
  T* data_;
  int sz_;

public:
  vector_t(void);
  vector_t(int sz);
  ~vector_t(void);
  void resize(int sz);
  int get_sz(void) const;
  T get_v(int pos) const;
  T& get_set_v(int pos);
  void set_v(T data);

  vector_t<double> suma(vector_t<T> b, double suma);
  vector_t<int> suma(vector_t<T> b, int suma);

  ostream& write(ostream& os) const;
private:
  void crea_vector(void);
  void destruye_vector(void);

};
```

referencia a `vector_t<int>::vector_t(int)' sin definir
main_vector.cpp:10: referencia a`vector_t::vector_t()' sin definir
main_vector.cpp:11: referencia a `vector_t<int>::vector_t(int)' sin definir
main_vector.cpp:13: referencia a`vector_t::suma(vector_t, int)' sin definir

refiriéndose al `main`:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<cassert>
#include "vector.hpp"
using namespace std;
// -std=c++11
int main (void){
  int suma=0;
  vector_t<int> a(8);
  vector_t<int> b;
  vector_t<int> a1(8);

  b.suma(a1,suma);
}
```

Quizá el problema esté con la forma que invoco los constructores, pero no sé.

Esta es la definición de los dos constructores:

```
vector:: vector_t(void){
    data_=NULL;
        sz_=0;
  }
  vector:: vector_t (int sz){
    data_=NULL;
    sz_=sz;
    int num;

    for(int i=1; i<=sz_;i++){
      cout<<"Introduzca el "<<i<<"número del primer vector "<<endl;
      cin>>num;
      data_[i]=num;
    }
  }
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Las definiciones deben ir en el mismo header (¿por qué? --> https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#templates-defn-vs-decl ); tienen faltas de ortografía y además les falta el parámetro template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Las plantillas tienen como particularidad que tanto la declaración como la implementación debe encontrarse **siempre** en un fichero de cabecera.

**¿Por qué?**

Básicamente porque el compilador, al encontrarse con una plantilla, no hace absolutamente nada... no genera nada de código. Se espera a encontrar usos de dicha plantilla para generar las especializaciones que se requieran.

**¿Pero por qué?**

Estaremos de acuerdo en decir que una plantilla tan pronto se podría especializar con un `int` que con una clase que a su vez contiene 20 vectores y 200 variables, ¿cierto? Y es fácil ver que el tamaño que ocupa un `int` va a ser bastante inferior al de la clase. En consecuencia el código generado para cada especialización puede ser completamente diferente.

Si, teniendo en cuenta lo anterior, obligamos al compilador a generar especializaciones al encontrarse con la declaración de la plantilla... ¿Qué especializaciones debe crear? ¿Todas? ¿Incluso la de tipos que todavía no conoce? Es algo irreal y que solo serviría para crear ejecutables insultantemente grandes.

Lo que sucede entonces es que el compilador se apunta las plantillas que va a encontrando pero no hace nada con ellas hasta que las mismas no se usan... en ese momento crea única y exclusivamente las especializaciones que se usan en el código.

**Unidad de compilación**

Vamos a hacer un pequeño inciso para explicar un detalle que es importante de cara a lo que viene después.

Si has probado a compilar alguna vez de forma manual, ¿No te ha llamado la atención que al compilador le puedas pasar todos los ficheros de implementación de una sola vez y que, sin embargo, sea necesario usar los `#include`? Dicho de otra forma... si al compilador ya le hemos pasado todos los cpp... ¿Qué sentido tienen las cabeceras?

El proceso de generar un ejecutable en C++ consta de 2 pasos:

- Compilación
- Ensamblado

En el proceso de compilación el compilador va a procesar cada cpp de forma individual. Para ello carga el cpp y lanza una utilidad llamada preprocesador. Este proceso es el que se encarga de interpretar los `#include`, `#define` y demás. Al encontrarse un `#include` lo sustituye por el contenido del archivo al que hace referencia.... si este archivo posee a su vez otros `#include` anidados el proceso se repetirá una y otra vez hasta que no quede un solo `#include` por procesar. Es decir, un cpp consta del propio archivo y de todas las cabeceras a las que referencie ya sea de forma directa o indirecta... y esa es toda la información que posee el compilador para realizar su trabajo. A este conjunto de ficheros se le llama unidad de compilación.

Después del proceso de compilación se lanza el enlazador. Su trabajo consiste en coger los ficheros de código objeto que se han generado durante la compilación para fusionarlos en un binario.

**Volviendo a las plantillas**

Pues bien, para entender el tema de las plantillas hay que tener en cuenta estos tres puntos:

- El compilador no hace nada con las plantillas hasta que no encuentra usos de las mismas
- Para compilar una plantilla necesita conocer su implementación
- El compilador solo dispone de la información contenida en la unidad de compilación (código referenciado mediante `#include`)

Con estos requisitos encima de la mesa es fácil entender por qué el código de las plantillas debe viajar junto. Si se separa la plantilla sucederá que el compilador no tendrá a su disposición la implementación de la plantilla y no sabrá como generar el código correspondiente.

**Errores en el código**

Si, por legibilidad, comodidad, el motivo que sea, decides poner por un lado la declaración de la plantilla y, por otro, su implementación (siempre en el mismo fichero), tienes que tener presente que debes indicar que las funciones pertenecen a una plantilla:

```
template<class T>
vector_t<T>::vector_t()
{
  data_=NULL;
  sz_=0;
}
```

**¿Y por qué hay que hacer esto?**

Son las normas del lenguaje. Además es una forma de diferenciar la plantilla original de una especialización:

```
template<class T>
class vector_t
{
// ...
};

// Especializacion explicita para el tipo int    
template<>
class vector_t<int>
{
  // ...
};

// Plantilla original
template<class T>
vector_t<T>::vector_t()
{
  data_=NULL;
  sz_=0;
}

// Codigo de la especializacion a int
template<>
vector_t<int>::vector_t()
{
  // ...
}
```